# Opening office documents from Sharepoint 2010 takes forever and seems to try to open dll-files from server!

Tags: office, sharepoint-server

When I try to edit an word (2010) document from Sharepoint (2010) it takes ages to open (~5 minutes for a 3mb file). If I just copy it to my desktop and open it from there, it's lightning fast. The behavior is the same whether I try to open it from the web ui or from the explorer view.

I open up fiddler to check what was going on behind the scenes and saw some really strange stuff. First of all I'm getting several 401 - unauthorized responses. I'm not sure why - I have the right permissions to the file - but it could have something to do that we recently migrated all the users to a new domain. But then follows something even more odd - a couple of requests for dll-files, that are supposed to be on my sharepoint server! See this screen dump:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/683612/fiddler_dump2.png

Have anyone seen this behavior before?

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I'm having the same issue. Are you able to fix this?

Comment: I am experiencing this isssue a lot of time. Sometime only for couple of documents (Not so big in size).<br>
But sometimes all the documents in 1 web applications stops opening and when I check in fiddler i get same error of 401 at cellstorage.svc. <br>
Let me know if you have found any answer to this issue Regards,
Vinod Naik

Comment: Hi Vinod! We realized that our installation was based on a preview version of Sharepoint 2010. When updated to the final version the problems stopped.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint + Office integrates in such a way that you aren't downloading the file so much as accessing it directly from the server, so it makes an interesting sequence of calls when you look in Fiddler. Some 401's are expected. The author.dll and _vti_rpc stuff is quite normal, as would calls to the cell storage service (I think the name is cellstorage.svc).

I have not seen it make calls to the MFC70ENU.dll that you highlight, I also don't think I've seen the wininet.dll.

Is the ZR-ACREO... file that is quite large the file you are downloading?

Comment: So you don't think the 401's are a problem? That's good to hear.

The document is about 8 mb. I've actually had no problem with smaller documents, but several of the larger. But I recreated a document the same size from zero with big pictures in it, and it was lightning fast to open it, so I'm starting to think it might be that the document is based on some old template with some strange references. Maybe macros. I'll have to dig into that...